# Keeping a recyclerView loaded during fragment switching in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm relatively new to coding, and now I've run into an issue that I can't seem to fix.

I just recently switched to a fragment based approach, rather than an activity based approach, and my issue (I think) is that my fragments are being destroyed upon loading another one.

You see, on my Home Fragment (auto generated inside Android Studio), I have a recyclerView that shows the User's "products". When I switch to another fragment, and then back, the Home fragment takes a while (aswell as uses a lot of CPU) to load. I suspect this is because the fragment is being destroyed upon switching. Since I am using Android Studio's built in fragment layout by the name of "Bottom navigation activity", I don't know how to tweak the navigation manager. Is there any way I can fix this?

This is my HomeFragment code, I'm sorry if it hurts your eyes.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mStorage: FirebaseStorage

    private lateinit var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager

    companion object {
        lateinit var productAdapter: RecyclerView
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //Initialize firebase references
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

        //Get user ID
        val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid

        //Initialize companion objects
        productAdapter = fh_productView

        fillProductView(uid)

        fh_addProduct.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(context, AddProductActivity::class.java))
        }



    }

    private fun fillProductView(uid: String) {
        val productList = MainActivity.productList

        fh_productView.apply {
            gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            val topSpacingItemDecoration = TopSpacingItemDecoration(20)
            addItemDecoration(topSpacingItemDecoration)
            fh_productView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            fh_productView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = ProductsAdapter(productList, "HomeFragment")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code, where you are switching between the fragments.

Comment: It is completely normal for a fragment to be recreated when showing a new one, thats how they work

Comment: Calling setRetainInstance(true) will prevent the Fragment from being re-created.